# Powershell: AD user MemberOf > Object Canonical name

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I would like to ask for help to create a powershell that asks for a AD username, then lists all the groups he's a member of, and also displays the Canonical name of the memberships objects.

for instance:

> John doe
>   Security Group 1 | domain.com/path/path/path/path
>   Security Group 1 | domain.com/path/path/path/path
>   and so on...

I tried to piece together components i found from all over, but i can't turn up anything viable. Appreciate any assistance!

Klinger

Comment: There is no easy way to get recursive group membership using the powershell commands, but you should look here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/09/04/token-bloat-troubleshooting-by-analyzing-group-nesting-in-ad/

Comment: @Ashigore I don't see where he asked for it to be recursive?

Comment: Show us what you have tried please

Comment: _I tried to piece together components i found from all over, but i can't turn up anything viable._ I have already answered, but the point here on SO is to always post your code when asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this :

```
#import AD PS module (mandatory)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#ask for user login
$userLogin = Read-Host "Enter Windows login (exact value)"

#get user info from AD including an additional property not in the default set
$userObject = Get-ADUser $userLogin -Properties DisplayName, MemberOf

#echo user's full name
$userObject.DisplayName

#for each group of which user is member
foreach($group in $userObject.MemberOf) {

    #get group info from AD including an additional property not in the default set
    $groupObject = Get-ADGroup $group -Properties CanonicalName

    #echo group name, a pipe, and group CN
    $groupObject.Name + " | " + $groupObject.CanonicalName
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This was exactly what i was looking for, and a reality check on how i approached it ;) will need to learn allot more about powershell. Thanks for getting me started.

Comment: Amended to ask for user login (and remove my actual login)

Comment: And added comments